# How to get ones' complement

Tags: c#

I need to find ones' complement of a decimal number given as an input. First I convert the decimal number to a binary number using the following code,

```
int decNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string binRep = " ";
int digi = 0;
do
{
    digi = decNum % 2;
    binRep = digi.ToString() + binRep;
    decNum = decNum / 2;
} while (decNum >= 1);
Console.WriteLine(binRep);
```

then when I do this,

```
int onesComplement= ~(int.parse(binRep)),
```

I get weird answers, for example when I give 8 as the input I get 1000 as the binary number but after using the tilde(~) for getting ones' complement I get -1001. I would like to know what am I missing here, and what best should I do to get ones' complement correctly?

Comment: @interjay: hey, it's close enough right? (retagged to C#)

Comment: use unsigned types if you are doing bit twiddling.

Comment: What output are you expecting?  int.parse(binRep) evaluates to a decimal 1,000 which in binary is 0011 1110 1000.  The one's complement of that is 1100 0001 0111 which is correctly being displayed as decimal -1001.

Comment: oh okay, i thought i need to get the ones complement of 1000-which is by itself a binary number after conversion of decimal number 8 to its binary form-1000 and so its complement must be 0001 is it not?

Answer (score 5):

By default the integer is parsed as if it is base 10, and you didn't specify a different base - `int.Parse()` doesn't offer this. You can use [`Convert.ToInt32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx) instead and specify the base the number is based on, in your case `2`.

> Converts the string representation of
>   a number in a specified base to an
>   equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

So use

```
int onesComplement= ~Convert.ToInt32(binRep, 2);
```

Your program can also be shortened to:

```
int decNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string binRep = Convert.ToString(decNum, 2);
Console.WriteLine(binRep);
int onesComplement = ~Convert.ToInt32(binRep, 2);
```

or even shorter if you don't need to print the binary output:

```
int decNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int onesComplement = ~decNum;
```

Comment: +1, I didn't know that using Convert.ToInt32 you can specify the base.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the weird numbers because when you do `int.Parse()` it is using base 10, so rather than 1000b it reads that as the literal base 10 integer 1,000. [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c09yxbyt.aspx) does not support binary numbers.

To get around this you could perform the bitwise complement using `~` on the original number and print those binary digits.

Here is a slight modification of your code to return the binary representation of a 32bit number, optionally inverting it:

```
static string GetBinary(string number, bool invert)
{
    // use unsigned ints to avoid negative number problems
    uint decNum = UInt32.Parse(number);
    if (invert) decNum = ~decNum;

    string binRep = String.Empty;
    uint digi = 0;
    do
    {
        digi = decNum % 2;
        binRep = digi.ToString() + binRep;
        decNum = decNum / 2;
    } while (decNum >= 1);

    return binRep;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

int.Parse thinks your string represents a decimal number (1000).